# Is the k-sum attack efficient in bilinear pairing variants?

Tags: pairings

From the k-sum definition, the objective is to solve something like:
$\sum_{i=1}^n c_i = v_1$ where $v_1$ is known.

If we use Elliptic Curve Points ($C_i$ and $G$) we can define a bilinear pairing variant:
$\prod_{i=1}^n  ê(C_i, G) = v_2$ where $v_2$ is known.

I suppose this would also be efficient to compute, but I'm not certain?

Comment: OK. I believe is not possible because the $ê$ function is not supposed to be invertible.